# Strange HTML ignoration of a tag

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink

HTML seems to completely and utterly ignore this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public_html/CSS.php?W=1"/>
```

It's in the head, and links to a PHP css stylesheet. Here's that stylesheet. I left some out of the if statement, purely to see if it was the statement itself not working.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>

div{
color:green;
}

body{
background-color:blue;
}

<?
if ($_GET["W"] == 1){?>

div{
color:green;
}

.Center{
align:center;
}

.Login{
border:5px solid green;
align:center;
}

<? } ?>
```

Comment: well done on creating a new word, "ignoration" :)

Comment: @rickyduck English needs more words ending in 'ation' :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `public_html` folder name is a typical name of the web root folder on the local disk file system. This folder is by itself **not** published in the web, only its contents are. The `href` attribute of the `<link>` element should point to a web path, not to a local disk file system path.

Assuming that `public_html` folder is indeed your web root folder and that the PHP file containing the `<link>` element is also there, then the CSS file should rather be linked as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.php?W=1"/>
```

Comment: Oops, second tiem I've made this mistake. So embarrasing, I've posted a similar question before, my memory is horrible. Apologies, and thanks for helping :)